# Does the Nestjs controller method have to be async if it returns a promise?

Tags: asynchronous, controller, nestjs

Very simple general question:

```
@Controller('something')
class SomeController {
  @Get()
  foobar() {
     return foo() // this returns a promise
  }
}
```

So in such a case, do I have to make the `foobar()` controller method async?
My understanding is that this is not necessary. NestJS will resolve the returned promise automatically. Making the method async is only needed if I wanna `await` inside.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, it's not necessary, Nest will view the promise as is and resolve it before sending the response, but it's generally a good practice to mark your promise returning methods as `async`, just to stay in the habit and be clear about what it is returning